# How can I patch Stagefright on an Elephone P6000 Pro?

Tags: stock-rom, stagefright

According to [this xda post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63025886&postcount=4) the Elephone P6000 Pro stock ROM is vulnerable to Stagefright. A Stagefright detector app confirmed this on my phone.

The Post links to [this patch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/bug-fix-stagefright-t3193219), but also mentions that the partitions do not match this phone.

I tried both flashing the [linked](http://www.needrom.com/download/stagefright-patch-p6000-pro-2/) modified version, and moving the files manually into the system.

However, the Stagefright detector app still shows that my phone is vulnerable to CVE-2015-6602.

What else can I do to fix Stagefright vulnerability?

---

**ls -l /dev/block/platform/*/by-name:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 custom -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 expdb -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 flashinfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 frp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 keystore -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 lk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 logo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 metadata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 nvdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 nvram -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 oemkeystore -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 para -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 proinfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 protect1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 protect2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 seccfg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 secro -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 tee1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 tee2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-05-30 00:59 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
```

---

**Steps taken to move the files:**

- Copy/paste using FX File Explorer with root addon
- Checked Permissions (were already rw-r--r--)

Comment: The only difference between those two packages that I see is that the latter loads `mmcblk0p21` as the `/system` partition instead of `mmcblk0p17`, so the claim is accurate.  Could you add the output of `ls -l /dev/block/platform/*/by-name/` and, for our sakes, spell out the exact steps you took to manually move the files?  I'd also suggest double-checking their permissions (should be 644).

Comment: @MatthewRead did that.

Comment: No further ideas?

Comment: You need to flash as newest Android accessible as possible.

Comment: I obviously did all firmware updates prior to using the device at all. There is no newer official ROM available.

Comment: There won't be any new ROM or security patch coming through official channels. Google Nexus(and now Pixel) are in fact the ONLY devices that receive monthly security patches addressing problems like this.  In the meantime, you can go into your Messaging App --> Settings-->Advanced and disable  'Auto-retrieve MMS'. This should mitigate at least part of the vulnerability.

Comment: @andDevW I have long since flashed a patched Cyanogenmod. Official channels once promised a marshmallow update for this phone, but as the post is now deleted I don't expect it to come at all. I just learned, never buy Elephone again. Their service is beyond bad, not only because of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **rooted** you can do the following things.
However your status will still show as vulnerable, stagefright can't be executed. We will disable the stagefright module.

**Method 1:** 
Use a root explorer app and navigate to the system directory.
Open the file called "build.prop" and add the following code completely at the bottom of the file:

media.stagefright.enable-player=false
  media.stagefright.enable-meta=false
  media.stagefright.enable-scan=false
  media.stagefright.enable-http=false
  media.stagefright.enable-rtsp=false
  media.stagefright.enable-record=false

This will completely disable the stagefright module on your device.
This won't have a huge impact on your device performance.

**Method 2**:
Use a build.prop editor app like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor&hl=en

Choose to add a line and type:
      media.stagefright.enable-player

and type false as value. Repeat that for all stagefright modules.